# Why $5x \cdot 8x - 3x \cdot (-3x) \ne 49^4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

$$5x \cdot 8x - 3x \cdot (-3x) = 40 x^2 + 9x ^2 = 49 x ^2 ,$$

but why is it not $49^4$? I just need this clarified and the rule behind this.

Comment: You'll need to add a bit more information to your question and to explain why you think it should be $49^{4}$. As it stands, your question is difficult to answer.

Comment: Why would you think it should be? It is $49^4$ when $x=\pm 49$, but why do you think it would be for any $x$? Do you mean perhaps that it should be $49x^4?$

Comment: or maybe just $x\neq 7^3$

Answer (score 0):

Think of $x^2$ as "apples" or some other quantity. $40x^2+9x^2$ then says "40 apples + 9 apples", which gives you 49 apples. Remember, "apples" was just another name for $x^2$, so the answer is $49x^2$.

If this does not answer your question, please let me know in the comments below.